# Breaking down the co power of a topological space

Tags: hausdorff-spaces

Consider a compact, Hausdorff topological space which is homeomorphic to its own co-power over an index set $I$, so $X \cong \prod_{i \in  I } X$. Is there necessarily another topological space, which is not a co-power of any other space, whose co-power over an index set is $X$?  In other words, if a space is homeomorphic to its own co-power, then can it be decomposed to some sort of atomic space?

Comment: Some Googling turns up a few uses of 'copower', but, since you mention a repeated self-product, you seem to be using it synonymously with 'power'.  What is the difference?

Comment: The terminology can be confusing: this is actually a [power](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/power) object, sometimes called a cotensor object. The dual (repeated disjoint union) is a copower object or tensor object.